Как указать свой путь запроса на сервер react-admin?
Как указать свой путь запроса на сервер для <Resource name='user' в getOne?
'use client';

import { Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';
import { useUserStore } from '@/store/use-user-store';
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import { ReportList } from './reports/list';
import customDataProvider from '@/api/custom-data-provider';
// import simpleRestProvider from "ra-data-simple-rest";
// import { axiosWithAuth } from '@/api/interceptors';
import { UserList } from './users/list';
import { UserEdit } from './users/edit';

const dataProvider = customDataProvider(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/api`);

const AdminsPage = () => {
    const { user, isLoading: isUserLoading } = useUserStore();
    if (isUserLoading) return null;
    if (!user?.isAdmin) return redirect('/');

    console.log('isUserLoading  ', isUserLoading, user?.isAdmin);

    return (
        <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider} >
            <Resource
                name='report'
                recordRepresentation='title'
                list={ReportList}
                // create={ReportCreate}
                // edit={ReportEdit}
            />
            <Resource
                name='user'
                recordRepresentation='title'
                list={UserList}
                edit={UserEdit}
            />
        </Admin>
    );
};

export default AdminsPage;






  @Get('get-by-id/:id') 
  @Auth()
  @HttpCode(200)
  async getById(@Param('id') id: string) {
    const data = await this.userService.getById(id)
    return data
  }

